# Conversion from CSV to TSV with content changes

Tags: powershell

I need to change CSV File to TSV, and also remove line breaks and double quotes.

Here's the code:

```
$filePath = "C:\Users\at1704171\Documents\Infinity Scorecard PBIX\converter"
$mkdir = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path (Join-Path -Path $filePath -ChildPath 'converted')
$files = Get-ChildItem (Join-Path -Path $filePath -ChildPath "*") -Include *.csv
$sep = "`t"
$ext = '.tsv'

foreach($file in $files)
{
    $filename = -Join($mkdir,"\",(Get-Item $file).BaseName,$ext)
        Import-Csv $file |
        ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter $sep |
        % { $_.Replace("`r"," ").Replace("`n"," ").Replace('"',"") } |
        Out-File -FilePath $filename -Encoding utf8
}
```

it's basically converting a CSV File to TSV, but also removing line breaks and double quotes. However I noticed that there are some "tabs" (`t) within the string so I needed to insert another line between "Import" and "Convert" to replace those "tabs" by a space

I do not understand how the syntax works so I literally copied the line below "Convert" since it executes the same function and did this, but it gives an error

```
$filePath = "C:\Users\at1704171\Documents\Infinity Scorecard PBIX\converter"
$mkdir = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path (Join-Path -Path $filePath -ChildPath 'converted')
$files = Get-ChildItem (Join-Path -Path $filePath -ChildPath "*") -Include *.csv
$sep = "`t"
$ext = '.tsv'

foreach($file in $files)
{
    $filename = -Join($mkdir,"\",(Get-Item $file).BaseName,$ext)
        Import-Csv $file |
        % { $_.Replace("`t"," ") } | --this is the line I added
        ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter $sep |
        % { $_.Replace("`r"," ").Replace("`n"," ").Replace('"',"") } |
        Out-File -FilePath $filename -Encoding utf8
}
```

anybody's help is greatly appreciated here, thank you guys

Comment: Can you add some sample input, desired output and the error message to the question? Do not use the comments to add data, it should all go into the question.